# CMake: Selectively relinking function calls

Tags: cmake, overriding, static-linking

I'm trying to link two different libraries (Intel MKL and Panua) containing PARDISO in my C++ project, compiled with cmake. I link Intel first and then want to overwrite the calls "pardisoinit" and "pardiso" such that Panua is used instead of Intel (but only for these two calls). Is this possible?

I haven't really found much regarding this. ChatGBT suggested
`target_link_libraries(<your_executable> -Wl,--undefined=pardisoinit -Wl,--undefined=pardiso <panuaLib>` and `target_link_libraries(<your_executable> -Wl,--undefined=pardisoinit panuaLib)`. It didn't work either way. I also tried `set_target_properties(<your_executable> PROPERTIES LINK_LIBRARY_OVERRIDE_<intelLib> <panuaLib>)`. Unfortunately I'm not very good with cmake...